# Create asynchronous task in cakephp

Tags: excel, asynchronous, nginx, cakephp-2.0

I need to export bulk of data in excel file using PHPExcel in cakephp. My code works perfectly for small ranges(max 1000 Records approx), but it Data size exceeds more than 1000 records, then nginx engine says **502 bad gateway** Error. Because its execution time is too high.

Now I like to do this task as asynchronous. Once Excel generation is Completed, then i need to notify the admin via email with a download Link.

[MY PAGE LINK](http://recordit.co/dhg6SZ8GN8)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Model that will behave as a Queue for the exports. Save the information needed to retrieve the data in a row, something like: 
id, request, filename, status, created, modified

Then create a Shell in app/Console/Command/ExporterShell.php and set a high PHP execution time with [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). ref: [CakePHP Shells](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell)

The Script needs to:

1. Read from that Queue table any unprocessed jobs
2. foreach, query for all necessary data to do the "export"
3. update status to "processing"
4. ... and processes them, perhaps with a limit of 3 or something small.
5. save out to your excel file and update the status column "complete", "error", etc... to keep it from being polled next time.
6. email the recipient (I'd keep a log of this somewhere, too)

Last, add this to /crontab to run it every 10 minutes or whatever frequency is appropriate like this:
*/10 * * * * root cd /var/www/html/project/app && Console/cake exporter >> /var/log/ExporterShell.log

Comment: Sorry for the late response.shall we have a skype discussion?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask here.

Comment: I like to know clearly..Here i can't post my code..so only...also  i done to create shell script through modal..but it doesn't ran asynchronously ,still it waiting to finished out..